# Should [sims-freeplay] and [the-sims-freeplay] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [sims-freeplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-freeplay) and [the-sims-freeplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sims-freeplay) be synonyms? They are relating to the same game. The only difference is that [sims-freeplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-freeplay) has a tag wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems sensible. This is now done:

[sims-freeplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sims-freeplay)  -> [the-sims-freeplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-sims-freeplay)